# Help pairing bluetooth headset/microphone with Samsung Galaxy Tab & Skype?

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-tab, skype, bluetooth-pairing

I have had some difficulty getting a bluetooth headset/microphone to work with the Samsung Galaxy Tab, and with Skype.

First, the bluetooth scanner can only find some headsets, not all of them. I tried to get a Motorola H350 headset to work, but it failed. Then I tried a Sprint Jawbone headset and it synced, but in Skype the microphone in it didn't work and it was using the microphone on the Galaxy Tab instead. I mean, I walked away from my tab and said "testing 1, 2, 3", and couldn't hear it. Instead, I heard someone near my tab saying, "testing a, b, c".

Second, I don't know if it's just a Skype issue or the Galaxy Tab hardware that's preventing Skype from picking up my voice over the paired bluetooth headset. Or perhaps it's the headset. Or perhaps I must use only a Samsung-brand headset.

In a nutshell, I want to use Skype calling on my Galaxy tab, and purchase a headset that lets me use the microphone in the headset.

Has anyone gotten this to work? What's the trick?

**EDIT**: I have since purchased [these wireless headphones](http://amzn.com/dp/B004FGNUH0/?tag=bettelearn-20) which also include a built-in mic. These sync'd up for audio output, but in Skype I could not get audio input. So, I then temporarily rooted my device (thank you z4 root tool) and edited /system/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf to enable some settings that Verizon Wireless and/or Samsung disables in the unit. I then reset the unit and did the headset repairing again. In the end, Skype would not do audio input from the headset. But I noticed this, however. The microphone on the Galaxy Tab is outstanding. It collects the audio input in such a way that drowns out background sound. So, in a sense, you can still use the headset with the tab and walk around in your cubicle, or even talk on a crowded bus, and for the most part it will clearly pick up your voice. It's a nice compromise since headsets with mics don't seem to work with the Galaxy Tab. This might be a symptom of Skype. Their tech support says they don't support audio routing through the headset. However, I noticed that headset audio on the Galaxy Tab also doesn't work with every other app I've tried as well.

Comment: No answer, but same issue: BT headset not being used by any function but the regular phone.
I would expect it work also for music player, or any sound coming from the system.

Comment: We r facing the problem with galaxy tab and blutooth ear phone connectivity. Earphone is not
connecting with galaxy tab p1000. Is it the problem with galaxy or skype.
Pls let me know. Deepak

Comment: I also have a similar problem. I have an HTC Desire and I just got a Jabra Arrow blue tooth and to my surprise all worked except for when using Skype! I do not know if it is an adroid/skype or a blue tooth incomparability issue. 

Anyone has got any comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have the proble second problem, and I found the skype staff said :Skype doesnt currently support routing the audio to a bluetooth device.
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=726263&st=0&gopid=3271265&
Maybe this is the reason...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I think the answer that Skype gives is rather lame. However, I edited my original question (see EDIT) with a compromise.

Answer (score 3):

Glad to see someone else with the same ambition, however, I just received a samsung wep870 headset and it's not behaving any different. According to samsung support, in order to use a headset in the first place, the headset must support a2dp. 
Perhaps someone else well have some luck making this work.

Answer (score 3):

Also from the Skype Community Forum Unofficial Android FAQ:

> Q. Why wont my bluetooth headset work with Skype.
>
> A. At this time skype doesnt support bluetooth devices. I am unable to comment on when or if this will be added

Answer (score 1):

I have a Sony Stereo bluetooth that is working on all the audio apps so far, including Skype. It's the (Sony) DR-BT10CX. I hope this helps. fardroid

Answer (score 1):

I just got a Jawbone Icon and it is working perfectly with all tab features AND Skype mobile on my tab and my husband's DROID X. Skype even rings to the BT headset. My tab is on Verizon if that matters to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that BT supports two channels.
(And the HTC Desire HD   or  Evo4) supports it well:

1 phone audio (which my android connects to my Navi, which has an built-in phone supporting BT kit and confcall quality speaker)

2 media audio (which my android connects to my FM rebroadcaster so I can pick it up on my cars' older radio, e.g. when I play podcasts, but still being able to have a phonecall: the media automatically stops playing, and I can touch the Navi to pick up the call)

I assume now, that Skype works intimately with the phone, on the media audio channel.
A paired, connected BT audioset , will most likely broadcast phone audio capability,
and Skype will be none the wiser...

floris.