# Problem with device pairing

Tags: bluetooth

I have problem in connecting android with a device. In froyo android 2.2 when I connect android with device it shows me pairing dialogue box and I successfully pair it. When i update my device from android 2.2 to  android 2.3 i.e. ginger bread pairing dialogue box is not showing. I am using Bluetooth chat example of android.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What device are you using? Is it an 'official' gingerbread release or have you installed it yourself?

Comment: I am using nexus one. yes it is official ginderbread release

Comment: Exact same issue here. With froyo on my device I could pair my BT hands free car kit just fine. Now with gingerbread 2.3.3 the pairing/PIN dialogue doesn't appear and I can't pair my device. The car kit is a Parrot built in device in a Peugeot 207cc.

boba

Comment: On Inspire 4G and LG P500 there aren't such problem. But they are also bases on 2.3 android. If PIN=0000, devices such as handset is connected automatically. You need only to select it in BT menu of Android phone.

Comment: Following similar Q&A might prove helpful: [Help pairing bluetooth headset/microphone with Samsung Galaxy Tab & Skype?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3829/help-pairing-bluetooth-headset-microphone-with-samsung-galaxy-tab-skype) / [Motorola Milestone Android - Bluetooth Issue - Paired but not connected](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12625/motorola-milestone-android-bluetooth-issue-paired-but-not-connected)