# Motorola Milestone Android - Bluetooth Issue - Paired but not connected

Tags: bluetooth, connection-issues, motorola-milestone

im using a Motorola Milestone. I have tried to connect to various bluetooth devices (laptops/other android phone) with this phone but none of them work. I can pair them But after pairing it says "Paired but not connected" I have tried all normal steps: Soft reset, Hard reset etc and the phone is running the latest OS 2.2.1

Intrestingly, If I download the application "Bluetooth File transfer" by medieval software - I can succesfully pair and connect via this application to my macbook and send files. However, for my purpose I need to use the bluetooth SPP profile off the phone (Which it claims to support).

So the question here is, Is it a software/hardware issue?

-Seems to me like a software issue, because It doesnt connect with my macbook with the official bluetooth settings menu, but works through a third party application?

any fixes? - I called motorola, but no luck as Im not in the states.

Mohit

Answer (score 3):

On a PC, it's often a driver issue. I followed these steps with mine last night:

**Before doing this, disable any processes using bluetooth devices**

- Download the 'Windows Mobile Device Center' ( current version is 6.1 ) which you can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/downloads/microsoft/device-center-download.mspx)
  this works for both Vista and Windows 7. I've tried it on both.
- Install the downloaded software but it may not look like it worked on Windows 7 PCs. Vista automatically configures the settings on the bluetooth devices but for those who have Windows 7, here are the things you should do:
- Go to 'Device Manager' from 'Control Panel' -Or- just right-click on Computer Icon and choose 'Properties' and then click on 'Device Manager'.- You'll see 'Bluetooth Peripheral Device' under 'Other devices'

[image]

- Right-Click it and click on "Update Driver Software" -Or- anyway you find it easy to bring up the Update driver window.
- Click "Browse My Computer for Driver Software" button.
- Click "Let Me Pick from a List of Device Drivers on my computer".
- Select 'Bluetooth Radio' from the list if it asked you to select and then in the next window, it will show a list of drivers with Company Names in one list and Drivers in another. In the Company List choose 'Microsoft Corporation', not only Microsoft.

[image]
[image]

- (From the drivers list there may be one or more drivers with the name "Windows Mobile-Based Device Support" with different driver versions. Select one or the latest. )
- Ignore any warnings and keep pressing next and then Finish at last. If all goes well, the last screen will show the message that device driver is successfully installed. ( Click 'YES' in the box )

[image]

Now, after manually updating the driver for your bluetooth device, in 'Device Manager' when you click on 'Bluetooth Radios', it should display one more item which will say 'Windows Mobile-based device support'.

**After you do this, restart all processes using bluetooth devices**

i got this process from [here](http://www.computers.nepalesemap.com/index.php?topic=3.0), refer to it if you need help.

Good luck!! :)